# Java tutorial method example

Tags: java, nio, buffered

Here there is a snippet taken from here:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

Path logfile = ...;

// Convert the string to a
// byte array.
String s = ...;
byte data[] = s.getBytes();

try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
                 logfile.newOutputStream(CREATE, APPEND))) {
    ...
    out.write(data, 0, data.length);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

However I cannot compile the logfile (which is a Path object) with newOutputStream method... only with Files.newOutputStream(path,StandardOpenOption..);

Comment: _However I cannot compile the logfile (which is a Path object) with newOutputStream method... only with Files.newOutputStream(path,StandardOpenOption..);_ Ok. So? What is the question?

Comment: Taken from where? No link. Did you mean [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)? If so, the simple answer is that the tutorial is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Path only contains information about where a file (or other thing) is located,  it does not provide any information on how to process it. As you know the Path is a file then you can use the File class to process it, in this case to open a stream on it.

In language terms Path does not have a newOutputStream method so it will fail to compile.

From Oracle documentation on [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

> Paths may be used with the Files class to operate on files, directories, and other types of files.

Comment: ok Mark check out the snippet in my question it uses it and it's written by Oracle